# Can I use blocking API on WinRT?

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, async-await

We are planning to use sqlite pcl library for WinRT store app using this project: https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/ . All the api is blocking. Will there be a problem  during app store review by Microsoft, if we use it?

Of course the api will be wrapped in `Task.Run`, somethin glike:

```
    public Task InsertTestSetForUser(TestItem testItem, long userid)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => InsertTestSetForUserInternal(testItem, userid));
    }
```

I knwo that there is an impl of sqlite with async API, but that would not be portable out of the box for Xamarin, which we use for porting to iOS and Android.

Comment: Hello, maybe I'm missing something but if you schedule the call as a Task it is not going to block. That is the whole point of the async / await / Task pattern. The Task schedules the call to execute on a worker thread. So scheduling the work to occur via a Task will never block.

Comment: Hi @JamesDailey-MSFT, thanks for your comment. I was just worried if MS will not have problem for example with the fact that I am not using async-ready api for SQLite (which is available). You are right, that by using tasks, it should be ok... I am creating my own async API.

Comment: You don't need to use an async-ready api. You can use the Task / await pattern or roll your own. The key as Fred pointed out below is to make sure that you don't block the UI thread for a prolonged period of time. Grab the UI message and then marshall the long running blocking call to a worker thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few requirements your app has to meet. The three most important ones regarding your question (imho) are these:

1. Your app has 5 seconds to start on the splash screen. If your database setup takes longer, consider using an extended splash screen or a background task.

   > The app must render the first screen or a splash screen within 5
   >   seconds after launch.
2. Your app must be responsive within 20 seconds (which is basically 5 + 15 seconds).

   > Within 20 seconds after launch, the app must be responsive to user
   >   input.
3. If there is an operation on the UI that takes more than 3 seconds to process, you have to use some kind of status indicator (e.g.: an indeterminate progress bar).

   > If an app performs an operation that causes the device to appear to be
   >   unresponsive for more than three seconds, such as downloading data
   >   over a network connection or transitioning between a screen or page,
   >   the app must display a visual progress or busy indicator.

So you see: There is no definition what blocking really means in the certification process. Just be sure to use Tasks for long operations that are triggered from the UI and display some kind of process / status to the user when the operation takes longer than expected. As long as your app stays responsive it will not fail certification (passing the WACK test is important, though).

For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh184840(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I thougth, but wanted to be sure.